# Not understanding solution to $\large \int_{|z-2|=2} \frac {5z+7}{z^2+2z-3}dz$ computation

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Not understanding solution to $\large \int_{|z-2|=2} \frac {5z+7}{z^2+2z-3}dz$ computation.

What was  shown in class:  $\large \int_{|z-2|=2} \frac {5z+7}{z^2+2z-3}dz=\large \int_{|z-2|=2} \frac {5z+7}{(z+3)(z-1)}=\cdots= \int_{|z-2|=2} \frac {2}{z+3}dz+\int_{|z-2|=2} \frac {3}{z-1}dz $

And then it is said that $\large \int_{|z-2|=2} \frac {2}{z+3}dz=0$ while $\large \int_{|z-2|=2} \frac {3}{z-1}dz=3 \cdot 2 \cdot \pi \cdot i$.

Can you please help me understand the last step? What's the difference bewteen the integrals?

Comment: The difference is the [winding number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number) of the poles.

Comment: In the first integral, the denominator does not have a zero within the disk $|z-2|\leq2$, so the integral is zero by the residue theorem.  On the other hand, $z-1$ has a zero within the disk $|z-2|\leq2$, so that integral might not be zero (and isn't zero in this case).

Answer (score 1):

[Cauchy's Integral Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula/%20Cauchy's%20integral%20formula) states $$ \oint_C \frac{g(z)}{z-a}dz =g(a)2\pi i.$$ for every $a$ in the interior of $C$.

Here $g(z) = \dfrac {5z+7}{(z+3)}$, and $a= 1$ hence $$ \oint_C \frac{g(z)}{z-1}dz = \dfrac {5(1)+7}{(1+3)}2\pi i = 6\pi i.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $D=\{z: |z-2|\leq2\}$, thus $\partial D=\{|z-2|=2\}$. Since $f(z)=2/(z+3)$ is clearly analytic in $D$, then by Cauchy's Theorem $$ \int_{\partial D} f(z)dz=0.$$
However, if $g(z)=3/(z-1)$, since $1 \in D$, by Cauchy's Integral Formula, letting $g(z)=h(z)/(z-1)$ with $h\equiv 3$ we get
$$
\int_{\partial D} g(z)dz=\int_{\partial D} \frac{h(z)}{z-1} dz= 2\pi  i \cdot h(1) = 2\pi i \cdot 3 = 6\pi i
$$